# How to convert font from a CSS external resource to a JSON

Tags: css, json, svg, fonts, adobe-illustrator

I need to use a JSON font file but I don't have the .ttf file or any other format I just have the font as active in adobe creative, and I'm able to use the SS font file as a external resource for web project. Does is any way to convert this into a JSON or to create some SVG in illustrator and corvert it to a JSON. ?

Comment: A JSON? A font file is binary data, what structure would you like to give it that would be representable in JSON? What's the purpose / end goal?

Comment: to use this library http://vara.akzhy.com/creating-fonts/  @Kaiido